# How to get url of a view by its name in ASP MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Let's say there's a view with a name `MyView`.

How can I get a url if this view by its name?

Comment: View names have nothing to do with url's. A url calls a controller method, not a view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View cannot have an URL.
An action which returns this view as a result can have an URL.

You can simply acquire action's URL using `UrlHelper`, it is available both in Controller class or CSHTML view file:

```
Url.Action("MyAction") // MyAction action of default controller
Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController") // MyAction action of specified MyController
```